# What are some popular EFL textbooks in Japan?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I'm looking for a shortlist of popular EFL textbooks that are commonly used in Japan. I'm mainly interested in textbooks aimed at beginner or intermediate adult learners (including young adults like high schoolers). In particular, I’m looking for typical textbooks used to prepare for the TOEIC test.

If you have used any textbook you mention, a brief evaluation would also be much appreciated!